# jQuery: copy direct image URL from input field to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

As part of an 8th grade chemistry project on the periodic table of elements, I'm trying to write a script that would take a direct URL for an image: (like this one: **http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=150x150&choe=UTF-8&chld=H&chl=http://goo.gl/dpZRKS**) from an HTML input field and output it in a div below as the image - not the direct URL. This would allow students to create an "Augmented Reality" periodic table of elements square using QR Codes that they could print and post on the wall which would provide other students with more information about the element that they researched.

I have achieved this for text (for the element name, atomic number, and atomic weight), but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this for the image.

You can view my progress here: http://jsfiddle.net/X85ra/

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    h1,h3{
        float:left;
        margin-right:20px;
    }
    td{
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.name').keyup(function () {

        // We create a variable called "finalname", that is equal to the text the user enters:
        var finalname = $(this).val();
        $('.title').text(finalname);


    });

    $('.name2').keyup(function () {

        // We create a variable called "finalname", that is equal to the text the user enters:
        var finalname = $(this).val();
        $('.title2').text(finalname);


    });

        $('.name3').keyup(function () {

        // We create a variable called "finalname", that is equal to the text the user enters:
        var finalname = $(this).val();
        $('.title3').text(finalname);


    });

});


</script>
</head>

<body>

<form action="">
    Atomic Number: <input class="name" name="" type="text"><br/>
    Atomic Weight: <input class="name2" name="" type="text"><br/>
    Element:<input class="name3" name="" type="text"><br/>
    QR direct URL:<input class="name4" name="" type="text">
</form>
<div>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><h3>Atomic Number:</h3><h1 class="title"></h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h3>Atomic Weight:</h3><h1 class="title2"></h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h3>Element:</h3><h1 class="title3"></h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h3>QR direct URL:</h3><p class="title3"></p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Create an image, set the attribute src with the url, append it to the div. TADA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set image src to `.name4` value like this:

```
$('.name4').keyup(function () {

    // We create a variable called "finalname", that is equal to the text the user enters:
    var finalname = $(this).val();
    $('.title3').attr('src', finalname);

});
```

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X85ra/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Append an image element and set its `src` to your image:

```
$('.name4').keyup(function() {
    var imgUrl = this.value; // no need to overuse jQuery here
    $('.title4').append($('<img>').attr('src', imgUrl));
});
```

Also, you seem to have a typo: there are two `title3`s in your code